# Rspec 'before' scope in context

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am getting an `undefinded local variable or method user` in this test. Anyone help?

```
context "[user IS signed in]" do     
  before do
      user = Fabricate(:user)
      league = Fabricate(:league)
      event = Fabricate(:event, league: league)
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in user
      ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:primary_leagues).and_return([league])
  end

  it "[creates a pick for a user]" do
    post 'create', {:pick => {user_id: user.id, event_id: event.id, league_id: league.id, points_pick: "home"}}
    Pick.all.size.should eq(1)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `before` block is declaring `user` as a local variable so it is out of scope within your `it` block.

The simplest way to fix this is to declare member variables in your `before` block, e.g.

```
before do
  @user = Fabricate(:user)
  @league = Fabricate(:league)
  @event = Fabricate(:event, league: @league)
  ...
end

it "[creates a pick for a user]" do
  post 'create', {:pick => {user_id: @user.id, event_id: @event.id, league_id: @league.id, points_pick: "home"}}
  Pick.all.size.should eq(1)
end
```

This works because `before` and `it` are executing in the context of the same (generated) class instance.

Alternatively you could declare your variables with `let` and leave the code example as it is, e.g.

```
context "[user IS signed in]" do     
  let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }
  let(:league) { Fabricate(:league) }
  let(:event) { Fabricate(:event, league: league) }

  before do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:primary_leagues).and_return([league])
  end

  it "[creates a pick for a user]" do
    post 'create', {:pick => {user_id: user.id, event_id: event.id, league_id: league.id, points_pick: "home"}}
    Pick.all.size.should eq(1)
  end
```

`let` will instantiate the given variable when it is first referenced and memoize the result.